# How serious is saying "Je t'aime"?

Tags: expressions

How serious is saying "Je t'aime"?

I want to get a Valentine's Day for a girl I like romantically. We've been together but never expressed love. She is from France so she'll know what it means.
How serious is saying "Je t'aime"? Is it a playful expression of affection? Or is it fairly serious?

Btw- The card has a picture of a cat on it with a rose in its mouth. I thought it was cute.

Comment: It is the same to say "I love you" so you can judge from there.

Comment: I would say it's fairly serious.

Comment: Is the “Je t’aime” pre-printed on the card (& therefore open to being interpreted as coming from the cat) or are you planning to add it in your own handwriting (which would be a bit harder to attribute to the cat)? (btw, if it’s just one of those “e-cards,” then none of it will have any meaning at all) Regardless, you’ll know soon enough what it meant to her or at least how she chose to take it. If she responds with “[Moi non plus](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Je+t%27aime...moi+non+plus)” you’ll know that she's a playful “keeper” who’s ready to take it anyway you want her to.

Comment: I would say it's even more serious than "I love you". I often hear english speakers use "I love you" in a not-so-serious way (to mean "You rock!" or "Thanks man!"), which rarely happens in French. "Je t'aime" is serious business.

Comment: @Fatalize I often hear and use je "Tu sais que je t'aime toi" in the same meaning as "You rock!" in english, but it may be only in Quebec and not in France.

Comment: What @oldergod said. It depends on how you say it and the context. Given the description you provided, I'd say not to worry about it appearing too serious. But then again, it depends on the recipient and on your past history together.

Answer (score 9):

On a valentine's day during dinner with a girl and the lovely view ?
There is no ambiguity about it, it's definitely in all seriousness ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Well it really means "I love you…".

Many people nowadays throw 'love' around like it doesn't have any true meaning, so the real answer is whatever loving someone means to you. Many people have different interpretations of love.

It is definitely more serious than:

> Je t'aime bien.

That just means "I like you", not to a significant other, but as a friend, pal, buddy, etc.

The bottom line is however you interpret 'love' is what "Je t'aime" means.

Answer (score 1):

In France, it's "serious".

Sometime a Mom could also say that to her child or the reverse, though (but I suspect it's an Americanism, and not that frequent).

Comment: "Sometime a mum could say that?"C'est une enfance vraiment triste si une maman ne  dit "je t'aime" que parfois...qu'est-ce qu'un parent est sensé dire à son enfant: I like you/je t'aime bien?
Sans aucun sarcasme de ma part :  serais-tu orphelin?

Comment: Question de génération je pense: beaucoup d'américanismes sont passés chez les jeunes parents français, probablement via les films et séries télé (je dit pas que c'est mal, juste que c'est nouveau). Le bécot sur la bouche de l'enfant en font partie, d'ailleurs.

Comment: Mes parents (plus souvent ma mère, il est vrai) m'ont souvent dit qu'ils m'aimaient, sans être influencés par les américanismes (question d'époque, effectivement). « On vous aime, on veut ce qu'il y a de mieux pour vous. On fait peut-être des erreurs, mais du mieux qu'on peut. » (en résumé) Quant au bisou sur la bouche, sans vouloir entrer dans un autre débat, ce n'est heureusement pas aussi généralisé que les « je t'aime » (les psychologues estiment que cette pratique a des effets néfastes sur les repères psychologiques de l'enfant).

Comment: Je pense que c'est plus une question de pudeur que de culture...Je dis "je t'aime" à ma fille au moins une fois chaque Jour, ne serait-ce qu'au coucher, et n'ai jamais pensé que cela puisse être incongru ou considéré comme une américanisation... Après il ne faut pas en abuser sous peine de vider ce mot de son sens, mais dire que ca n'est pas fréquent me semble au mieux très pessimiste... Après, bon, elle n'a que 3 ans, j'imagine que ca va vite la souler quand elle sera plus grande ;-) Mais là on glisse vers un sujet "Parenting" plus que "French Language" :-)

Comment: Non non; où à la rigueur vers un sujet "linguistique". Ton usage reflète l'étendue du *sens* que tu voie dans le mot, ça n'est pas (qu')une question de pudeur.   De même par exemple que, côté insultes, il y a un certes aspect culturel, un aspect effronterie (calibré en fonction du cuturel), mais aussi un aspect "que signifie vraiment pour moi le mot que j'emploie".

Answer (score 1):

On peut toujours dire « je t'aime » à une fille, elle en fait ce qu'elle veut !
Je t'aime peut se traduire par : ''I love you'' ou bien ''I like you'' !

Comment: On peut toujours dire ''je t'aime'' à une fille, elle en fait ce qu'elle veut ! Je t'aime peut se traduire par: ''I love you'' ou bien ''I like you'' !