# How serious is saying "Je t'aime"? [already asked, but I'm seeking more detail]

Tags: sens

The question has been answered in part in this post: [How serious is saying "Je t'aime"?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17674/how-serious-is-saying-je-taime), with Papa Poule answering:

> ... you’ll know soon enough what it meant to her or at least how she chose to take it. If she responds with “Moi non plus” you’ll know that she's a playful “keeper” who’s ready to take it anyway you want her to. – Papa Poule Feb 6, 2016 at 17:41

Getting to the nub of my question: did the Serge Gainsbourg song *Je t'aime…moi non plus* change the meaning of the phrase *je t'aime*? If I recall correctly, before the Jane Birkin version was released in 1969, it was not a strong statement, and meant more like *Je t'aime bien* does today. Back in those distant days it took some flowers to get the message across.

Comment: Please clarify, is your question about if the song changed the meaning of Je t'aime ?  That's your title perhaps, otherwise this is a duplicate *and* a matter of opinion.  Please take a moment to see the [help] et bienvenue sur French Language SE.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have read the help center advice on posing a question. This is a somewhat duplicated question, and *definitely* seeking opinion.

Comment: [I did not know posts could only be edited for 5 minutes!) Thank you for the response. I have read the help center advice on posing a question. This is a somewhat duplicated question, and *definitely* seeking opinion, since no one is more confused than a man born in Paris, what with the locks on Pont des Arts, and le mur des je t'aime in Monmartre, plus the _city of love_!

Comment: If we look at 19th c. literature, we can see that the difference between *je t'aime* and *je t'aime bien* was the same as it is today. Flowers or no flowers.  *Je t'aime bien* was and still is a lesser statement.

Comment: Is *je t'aime* serious? Yes. Does Gainsbourg's song change its meaning? No.

Comment: @None, thank you. I will take flowers every second week.

Comment: @Jilliagre, merci. I will avoid Monmartre.

Comment: By the way, you might want to adjust you nickname to *VacheEspagnole*.

Comment: Done! I guess I was thinking in FranEspanol. :)

Answer (score 2):

*How serious is saying "Je t'aime"?*

Serious.

*Did the Serge Gainsbourg song Je t'aime…moi non plus change the meaning of the phrase je t'aime?*

No, *je t'aime* has the same meaning it still has today in that song. The *moi non plus* line reflects the particular relationship between the lovers, asymmetrical and/or with ups and downs.

*If I recall correctly, before the Jane Birkin version was released in 1969, it was not a strong statement, and meant more like Je t'aime bien does today.*

No, it was already a strong statement in 1969, as it has been for many centuries.

*Back in those distant days it took some flowers to get the message across.*

Flowers could complement or substitute the words, but were not obligatory.